# How to use HTTP/2 connection instead of session cookies?

Tags: http, firefox, session-cookies, http2

is it possible to use HTTP/2 connection (TCP session) for session tracking,
instead of session cookies (this will help when cookies are disabled)?

HTTP/2 was published 2015-05-14 ([RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540))

HTTP/2 was enabled by default in FF from 2015-01-13 ([v35](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35)).

List of [HTTP/2-server](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) implementations ([http2-katana](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/http2-katana), etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/2 connections are long lived, but not persistent; an H2 connection can go away and die at any time. And this is the internet, TCP connections can be torn down for no apparent reasons :-). If you requirements for HTTP session handling can deal with that, then yeah, you can likely just use your (one) H2 connection as a session "cookie". It would be very unreliable and unpredictable at best.